# Moving table data to another table if table is not exists

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am generating dynamic script to move data into another database if table is not present then i want to create. This script runs perfectly if it execute directly. But gives error if that script string execute by execute statement. i have tried exec also.

```
declare @temp as varchar(max)
set @temp='select * into Allocation_Archive.dbo.Users from Users'
execute @temp
```

Error

```
Database 'select * into Allocation_Archive' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Option 1

1. Add a `USE database` statement to your variable or specify the full object name including database and schema.
2. Wrap the `@temp` variable in parentheses

For example:

```
declare @temp as varchar(max)
set @temp='select * into Allocation_Archive.dbo.Users from ThisDatabase.dbo.Users'
execute @temp
```

### Option 2

Don't use:

```
EXECUTE @temp
```

Instead use

```
EXEC sp_executesql @temp
```

You will also need to change your `@temp` variable to be `nvarchar(max)`

Comment: Was just writing that into the answer :)